# parameter explain from move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, parameter, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI, can someone explain to me what it is oscillation_timeout parameter from move_base? I can't found info of it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299727/parameter-explain-from-move_base/) by [Diego_Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/36777/diego_perez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Under Parameters in the roswiki [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) package it is stated that:

```
oscillation_timeout (double, default: 0.0)
How long in seconds to allow for oscillation before executing recovery behaviors. A value of 0.0 corresponds to an infinite timeout
```

This means that if the value is 0 when the robot gets stuck it will perform osculation movements(example: move few cm back and front constantly) until it gets unstuck or fails the path planning and enters recovery behaviors to get unstuck. The problem is that these osculation movements can be from few seconds to lets say 10 minutes (who knows, maybe even hours). That is why this parameter allows you to specify how many seconds do you want the osculation occur and avoid those long/infinite osculations and enter the recovery behaviors.
In some projects I have seen that this time is usual set from 3-5 seconds but it is up to the custom requirements.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Diego_Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/36777/diego_perez/) on 2018-08-06**:
Thank you so much about explanation.